# Django CreateView don't call form_valid neither form_invalid or post()

Tags: django

I have a CBV :

```
class Publish(CreateView):
    success_url = '/'
    template_name = "article/publish.html"
    form_class = ArticlePublish
    model = Article

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('ee')
        return super(Publish, self).get(request)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('jj')
        return super(Publish, self).post(request)
    def form_valid(self, form):
        print('dd')
        form.instance.author = User.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
        return super(Publish, self).form_valid(form)
    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print('cc')
        return super(Publish, self).form_invalid(form)
```

When i submit this form:

```
class ArticlePublish(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Article
    fields = ['title', 'synopsis', 'content']
```

with the following HTML:

```
<form action="" method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

I get:

```
[13/Oct/2016 16:33:53] "GET /publish/ HTTP/1.1" 200 591
ee
[13/Oct/2016 16:33:56] "POST /publish/ HTTP/1.1" 200 591
ee
```

So it seems that even using post, with the correct modelForm still don't call the form_valid or form_invalid method. Even the post method dont get called.

Someone have an idea of what is going on please?

Comment: post your urls.py. Also are you using any middlewares ?

Comment: Not at work so dont have the code, but yes i added a middlware that was putting a login_form in the request.

Answer (score 0):

The super calls for both the post method and the get method should include *args and **kwargs:

```
return super(Publish, self).post(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

This will pass along other information including the form data.

Answer (score 0):

It was actually the middleware i created that was causing this.
Thanks.